# DigitalOcean Server goes down after PHP-FPM process uses all ressources

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I have a problem in my wordpress website hosted on DO on top of a LAMP stack using ServerPilot.io
Starting yesterday, I noticed that sometimes the server goes down and the browser either displays a 524 error (bad gateway) or a timeout error. When I check my DO graphs I notice that the CPU and RAM usage goes all the way from 5% to 100% and stays that way, and the Disk I/O goes from little to more than 100 Mbps without any particular reason. The process that uses most of the resources and causes this problem is the php-fpm process. I am using this configuration for months and this is the first time this happens, I did not add any plugins nor change the code, and I am using Wordfence and I do not see any attack on the website. Please if anyone had the same issue please share your thoughts. Thank you.

PS: check screenshots for more in-depth understanding.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the apache error log have to say?

Comment: Disk IO == swap usage. Your server ran out of memory. 1. Check your apache logs for that time to see why. 2. Decrease the max number of FPM workers that can spin up at once to prevent your server from doing this.

Comment: KayakinKoder how can I check the apache log?

Comment: Sammitch how can I decrease the max number of FPM workers? and how can I configure a swap disk?

Comment: To get the error logs, notice the error message on the webpage you are visiting. In bold red letters it says: "Detailed information about this error ..."  The file it lists there is where you will find the error log. So the error log file is located on the server at the location `srv/users/SYSUSER/log/....`

Answer (score 0):

Create one swap partition for your DO server .

reference : http://www.elinuxbook.com/how-to-create-a-swap-partition-in-linux/

Also check your /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm-event.conf **or** /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm-worker.conf file:

MinSpareThreads       25

MaxSpareThreads       75

ThreadsLimit          64

ThreadsPerChild       25

Check /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf

According to your Server :

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>

    ServerLimit              925
    StartServers             4
    MinSpareThreads          25
    MaxSpareThreads          75
    ThreadLimit              64
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers        925
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000


</IfModule>
```

then do this

Save your settings and restart your apache and php-fpm processes

sudo service apache2 restart

sudo service php7.1-fpm restart

Could you paste here your apache logs and htaccess file .